# How would I parse this url to get the id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to parse this url using ruby to get the id 33: `http://www.domain.com/?id=33`

How would I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With an regular expression like `/\d+\z/`. You can build such one using [rubular](http://rubular.com/) for example. The given expression extracts the id under the condition, that no other characters follow post the id and the id itself contains only digits.

Comment: cool... how would I extract the id into a variable with the regex?

Comment: @user730569: with <code>match</code> like <code>id = url.match(/\d+\z/)[1] and "url" being your url.

Comment: and how would I get the current url?

Comment: @user730569: [This](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=r106/webreader.rb) could help.

Comment: This solution is very fragile. It assumes that the value is always at the end of the URL, however the URL spec doesn't require consistency in parameter positions. A parser is a much better choice.

Comment: @the Tin Man: I said this also in my answer. Furthermore i recommended the answer of @mu is too short

Answer (score 8):

You could use a regex but you'd be better off using the libraries to ensure that you're properly handling all the various idiosyncrasies of URLs:

```
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'
h  = CGI.parse(URI.parse('http://www.domain.com/?id=33').query)
id = h['id'][0].to_i
# You now have the id parameter as a Fixnum
```

As a bonus, this will give you some familiarity with the standard libraries.

Comment: +1 "this will give you some familiarity with the standard libraries" Better to not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression via match, i.e.

```
id = url.match(/.*\=(\d+)/)[1]
```

where url = "http://www.domain.com/?id=33"

ian.

Comment: Yep, this code sets the 'id' variable to just the id.  So, for your example id would equal 33.

Comment: As in @macs answer, this is very fragile and will break if the parameter position changes.